# OpenVINO can't detect GPU

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gpu, openvino

After completing the installation of OpenVINO 2021.3 the installer prints:

```
Missing optional prerequisites
-- Intel® GPU is not detected on this machine
-- Use Intel-optimized version of OpenCV
```

I have tried to follow many guides from Intel but I couldn't resolve the issue. I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Where should I start?
I am using an AWS EC2 with an Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz .

The output of `sudo lshw -C display` is:

```
 *-display:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Amazon.com, Inc.
       vendor: Amazon.com, Inc.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 1e
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:10 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff
```

EDIT: I tried `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` with no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this CPU does not have an integrated GPU.  Generally server parts come without GPUs